# Electric flux and electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Consider a point charge located at the vertex of a cone. Then field lines are perpendicular to the normal of the curve surface then there is no flux through the curve surface. But mathematically we get flux through the curve surface. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field line emerging through flat surface of the cone contribute to the flux through the cone. Some field lines pass just along the curved surface, but some, pass from the empty interior of the cone. The flux is actually due to flux emerging from the base of the cone. So the fraction of flux through cone will be solid angle subtended by vertex of cone divided by total solid angle($=4\pi$)

Comment: But in that case calculation would show that the flux emerged from the flat surface is $\frac{q(1-cos\delta)}{2\epsilon_0}$ where $\delta$= semivertical angle of the cone. Whereas two cones having their vertexes joined will create perfect closed volume making each cone having a resultant flux passing through $\frac{q}{2\epsilon_0}$ Now what is the misconception/calculation with the factor $\frac{qcos\delta}{2\epsilon_0} $passing through from any surface other than the flat?

Answer (score 1):

There is no flux passing through the curved surface. All the flux passing through the cone passes through its base.

Comment: But in that case calculation would show that the flux emerged from the flat surface is $\frac{q(1-cos\delta)}{2\epsilon_0}$ where $\delta$= semivertical angle of the cone. Whereas two cones having their vertexes joined will create perfect closed volume making each cone having a resultant flux passing through $\frac{q}{2\epsilon_0}$ Now what is the misconception/calculation with the factor $\frac{qcos\delta}{2\epsilon_0} $passing through from any surface other than the flat?